# How to mask sprites in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mask, ccsprite

I've read Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on sprite masking: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0. However, my understanding of openGL is poor, and this tutorial doesn't produce the effect I desire. What I would like to do is to mask one sprite/layer with another, and move the sprite behind the mask to create a "shiny" animation, like so:

[image]

Additionally, how could I make the mask dynamic (ex: changing the text string), and how could I make a sprite or layer count its children as part of the mask?

Answer (score 1):

I think you con do that with an animation, put the "reflection sprite" under the "mask sprite" and then move the "reflection sprite" from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Github repository will help you.

https://github.com/tonybeltramelli/Cocos2D-Mask-Shader

Comment: Thanks, but that just generates a new static texture from the mask and sprite textures. I need to move the mask as part of an animation.

Comment: That's a good up to date mask shader, however just as you say it does not support animation. I am looking into this as well.